# Returning promises from callbacks inside async functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below is the pattern I use to return promises from inside of async functions:

```
async call(id: string, inputs: Array<string>): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        await this.loadCache();

        async.each(inputs, async (k, c) => {
            try {
                c(); // Do something here
            } catch (error) {
                reject();
            }
        }, async e => {
            await this.callInternal(id);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see there are several Promise returning functions that I call inside the promise constructor with await. I am not a great Javascript/Typescript programmer so I want to know if there is a better pattern to create this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is similar to what you're doing:

```
async call(id: string, inputs: Array<string>): Promise<void> {
  await this.loadCache();
  await Promise.all(inputs.map(input => input())); // see below
  await this.callInternal(id);
}
```

An `async` function already returns a promise, so you don't need to wrap the contents of `call` with a new promise.

I'm not clear what the `async.each()` is doing in your example code: it's calling `c`, which is the async iterator callback, but I assume you want to call `k`.

It also looks like that function is synchronous, otherwise you would have passed either a callback, or you woud have prefixed the calls with `await`.

I made a guess that `inputs` is an array of functions that return promises, and that each function needs to be called in parallel.

Comment: I'm guessing the return type of the function should be Promise<void>

Comment: @Daryl I have very limited TS experience, so I have no idea :D

Comment: it should be a void, since you aren't actually returning anything i.e. No resolve(obj), just a resolve().

Comment: @Daryl makes sense :)

Comment: @robertklep async.each is a function from async library which enables me to call some other functions in parallel. After reading more about promises, I saw that it's really not needed here.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit I know what it is, it just wasn't clear to me how it was being used :) But good to hear that you were able to replace it with promises, which are a much better fit when using `async/await`.